# Raw point cloud data to GIS format

Tags: geojson, 3d, point-cloud

I am trying to create 3D maps. I have raw 3D point cloud data but unable to convert it to any GIS data format such as GeoJSON. How should I store 3D information in GeoJSON format?

Comment: Is your point cloud LAS data? Are you open to formats other than GeoJSON? What software do you want to use the data in? Packages like Global Mapper and ArcGIS can visualise LiDAR data in ASPRS LAS format.

Comment: My point cloud data is in .pcd format (using stereo camera). Yes, any other format will also do good. I am trying to build maps using mapbox api. I want to convert it to a gis format which can be imported to a map as a layer.

Comment: I'm not sure about .pcd format, can you open in notepad++ (or other good text editor)? Is it X,Y,Z data with .pcd extension?

Comment: yes, you can open pcd file in notepad. It has xyz fields. (lat long alt)

Comment: If you have QGIS you can import it and convert to points https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73804/how-do-you-import-simple-xyz-in-qgis then export to GeoJSON as needed.